# Replacing lists in codenameone

Tags: java, listview, user-interface, codenameone

According to [this page](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/avoiding-lists.html), `com.codename1.ui.List` should be avoided. So I'm using a `Container` as a replacement as recommended and it works well with my test data with tens or hundreds of items. However, there's no upper limit for the element count and I'm sure, I'll need some optimizations. I don't think, pagination would make sense for the user, so I'll need to be able to show (tens of) thousands of items.

All items are displayed as containers, each consisting of about a dozen labels. The height of every container is the same, so I'm thinking about initially using an empty container and filling it only when it gets scrolled to. For this, I need to know

- How to force the empty container to the same height as a filled one?
- How to find out, what items need to be shown? I could use a `ScrollListener`, but there's probably a simpler way?
- (subjective) Is this a dumb idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's a mistake. List supported millions of entries. Unfortunately trying to scroll through them with finger swipes was unrealistic. This is easy in the desktop where you have a scrollbar but just out of the question in touch based user interfaces.

Imagine getting a phone call or accidentally pressing the home button while scrolling 10k entries. Or something very annoying that happens to me a lot in the reddit app: when you press their logo by mistake (which can happen if I press the side of the phone too hard) it jumps to the top. Try starting the scrolling over again after that...

If this is a real case and every item height is the same then you can use a `List` for that extreme case. This is exactly the reason behind the list renderer architecture. Notice that its performance advantages start kicking in when you reach the 10k entries or higher... But I don't think the UX is realistic on a device.

Comment: As I wrote, most users will deal with a few dozens of lines, but there're exceptions and there's no limit. I'm afraid, you're right with the UX being the bigger problem, so I'll need to use pagination and/or filtering and there'll no huge list.